# Update a single cell in a row of 6 in a table, Microsoft Powerflow

Tags: excel, power-automate

As the title states, I am trying to update one cell out of 6 in a particular row in a table.

Data is being pulled from a Microsoft Form.
The form has six questions, each with three options from which to choose.
I need to be able to update the data in one cell, and leave information in the other cells alone.  There may be information in the other cells which needs to be preserved.

Currently the flow successfully

- retrieves the correct information from the form
- retrieves the correct row on the table
- updates the one (or more) cell in the row

and it incorrectly erases the data in other cells.

**Retrieving proper row**

[image]

**Information to be updated**

[image]

**Destination row in table, name purposefully removed**

[image]

In these images SWI 001 is supposed to be updated, and all five SWIs below should remain unchanged.  SWIs above 001 are on a second form, and are unaffected.
Currently SWI 001 is updated, but all five other cells are erased.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re retrieving the row with all attributes in the first place, to fix your issue, simply load the dynamic content (i.e. the existing value of each field) back into the update step for all other fields that you don’t want to affect.

It seems superfluous but it will ensure the data remains.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It lead to the correct actions.  In addition, I had to add additional "Get a Row" between each "Update a Row", so that each time the Flow was getting the most up to date responses.

Comment: If my answer helped then can you please flag it as the answer? It rewards those who helped and helps others with the same issue.